# Empty path name is not legal Error

Tags: c#, sql-server

I'm trying to save a 2 images to my database but i keep on getting the above error, i have tried a lot but just cant solve it.

```
    string fileName = "";
    string fileName2 = "";
    private void SaveReq()
    {
        try
        {
            byte[] img = null;
            byte[] img2 = null;
            FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
            FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(fileName2, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);

            BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(fs);
            BinaryReader br2 = new BinaryReader(fs2);
            img = br.ReadBytes((int)fs.Length);



            img2 = br2.ReadBytes((int)fs2.Length);
            SqlConnection CN = new SqlConnection(mysql.CON.ConnectionString);
            string Query = "insert into BUILD_LIC (ID,KROKY,KROKY_3AM) values('" + txtID.Text + "',@KROKY,@KROKY_3AM)";
            CN.Open();
            mysql.COMMAND = new SqlCommand(Query, CN);
            mysql.COMMAND.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@KROKY", img));
            mysql.COMMAND.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@KROKY_3AM", img2));
            mysql.COMMAND.ExecuteNonQuery();
            CN.Close();

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

if i delete one of the filestreams(fs,fs2) the code work & save image put this only for one & i want to save the two images could u show me how to do that by correcting my code

Comment: Did you debug your code? Which line gave this error?

Comment: The exception message is telling you exactly what's wrong. The exception stack trace will tell you exactly where it's going wrong. Which part are you having trouble with?

Comment: You set both `fileName` and `fileName2` to empty strings, and then pass them into 'FileStream` constructor.  What did you expect to happen?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that the filename value has a valid file path.

From [FileStream Constructor (String, FileMode, FileAccess)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/tyhc0kft.aspx)

> Throws ArgumentException if path is an empty string (""), contains
>   only white space, or contains one or more invalid characters.

You might want to have a look at [File.Exists Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.exists.aspx)

> Determines whether the specified file exists.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is telling you exactly the issue, and it appears obvious in the code you posted:

```
string fileName = "";
string fileName2 = "";
```

You then call the `FileStream` constructors with the above variables, but I don't see where you've set them to anything other than `""`:

```
FileStream fs = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
FileStream fs2 = new FileStream(fileName2, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
```

You'll need to give valid path/filenames to those two variables to resolve this error.  For example:

```
string fileName = @"C:\Temp\File1.txt";
string fileNAme = @"C:\Temp\File2.txt";
```

Comment: if i delete one of the filestreams(fs,fs2) the code work & save image put this only for one & i want to save the two images could u show me how to do that by correcting my code

Comment: The code you have for both filestreams is the same - if one works, the other one should too unless there's a problem with the file or the stream.  When you use both filestreams, do you have valid paths for both streams?